# Android shared preferences cached?

Tags: android, settings

The answer is at the bottom.

I've added a modification to the 4.0.4 browser which adds a new preferences section. When the browser is launched, the value is read in correctly and seems to get cached. I added a log event any time getMaxTabs is used by Controller.java and it's only read on first launch. If I change the setting nothing happens. But if I kill the browser and re-launch after changing the setting, the new value is read in correctly. Is there a way to force this setting to be re-cached on change?

I am looking at SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener but I don't see HOW to have that variable re-read forcibly.

```
int getMaxTabs() {
    Context mContext = mActivity.getApplicationContext();
    SharedPreferences mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
    String numTabs = mPrefs.getString(PreferenceKeys.PREF_MAX_TABS, "20");
    int t = Integer.parseInt(numTabs);
    Log.i("max open tabs", "max: " + t);
    return t;
    // The original content of getMaxTabs is below
    // return mActivity.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.max_tabs);
}
```

So the log item only appears the first time the browser is launched. The new preference is set because if I change it and kill/relaunch the browser, the new value is reflected. I need to either not cache this setting or force the cache to be refreshed on change, which would be more efficient.

src/com/android/browser/preferences/TabsPreferencesFragment.java

```
package com.android.browser.preferences;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;

import com.android.browser.BrowserSettings;
import com.android.browser.PreferenceKeys;
import com.android.browser.R;
import com.android.browser.search.SearchEngine;

public class TabsPreferencesFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Load the XML preferences file
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.tabs_preferences);
    }
}
```

res/xml/tabs_preferences.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <ListPreference
        android:key="max_open_tabs"
        android:defaultValue="20"
        android:title="@string/pref_max_open_tabs"
        android:entries="@array/pref_max_open_tabs_choices"
        android:entryValues="@array/pref_max_open_tabs_values"
         />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

This is how it is called in src/com/android/browser/TabControl.java

```
private int mMaxTabs;

TabControl(Controller controller) {
    mController = controller;
    mMaxTabs = mController.getMaxTabs();
    mTabs = new ArrayList<Tab>(mMaxTabs);
    mTabQueue = new ArrayList<Tab>(mMaxTabs);
}

boolean canCreateNewTab() {
    return mMaxTabs > mTabs.size();
}
```

**SOLUTION**
The answer lies here, in packages/apps/Browser/src/com/android/browser/TabControl.java

Around line 55 we see:

```
/**
 * Construct a new TabControl object
 */
TabControl(Controller controller) {
    mController = controller;
    mMaxTabs = mController.getMaxTabs();
    mTabs = new ArrayList<Tab>(mMaxTabs);
    mTabQueue = new ArrayList<Tab>(mMaxTabs);
}
```

The TabControl object is constructed one time at browser launch. Here we define mMaxTabs by calling mController.getMaxTabs().

Around line 155 canCreateNewTab is defined, using mMaxTabs.

```
boolean canCreateNewTab() {
    return mMaxTabs > mTabs.size();
}
```

Since mMaxTabs is a static value it will never change on preference update.

The solution is this.

```
/**
 * Construct a new TabControl object
 */
TabControl(Controller controller) {
    mController = controller;
    mTabs = new ArrayList<Tab>(mMaxTabs);
    mTabQueue = new ArrayList<Tab>(mMaxTabs);
}

boolean canCreateNewTab() {
    return mController.getMaxTabs() > mTabs.size();
}
```

Now every time a new browser tab is requested, the pref setting is verified.

Comment: Can you post your code? In my experience SharedPreferences immediately reflects changes made with the SharedPreferences.Editor object. My guess is there is some other reason that your value is different than what you are expecting.

Comment: I have code in a few places for this. Do you want to see the Controller code? The SharedPrefs code?

Comment: Anything where you are calling .put[Type]() on the Editor, or .get[Type] on the SharedPrefs.

Comment: This is where it's read. Anything that reads the max tabs makes a call to getMaxTabs. I have a PreferenceFragment that sets it.

Comment: paste the code where you are updating/changing the value

Comment: How often is getMaxTabs() being called? If you are polling for this int often you should create your mPrefs reference in your onCreate method and hang on to it so you don't have to re-create it each time. Also is there any specific reason you are using a String and converting to an int when SharedPrefs is capable of storing a plain ole int?

Comment: getMaxTabs is called any time a request to create a tab is made. But since the value is cached, the cached version is returned. See, this used to be a static value, hard coded in res/values/integers.xml but I wanted to make it changeable and the only problem is that it's cached.

Comment: Tim, when you attempt to create a tab canCreateNewTab is called to see if the maximum number of tabs has been exceeded. If it is, you get a toast warning, otherwise you get a tab. "mMaxTabs = mController.getMaxTabs();" does the checking but since the value in the cache is not updated after I change it in settings, I am still using the previous value.

Comment: Please do not put "solved" in the title.